# Is it possible to use the Spring MVC on JBoss App server?

Tags: jboss, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use Spring MVC on JBoss App server?
If so, how?

Used the Spring MVC with Tomcat Apache server, but now i have to move my project to a JBoss app server.

But i'm getting an error, and i'm not sure why. It seems like i can't use my classes.

```
125 ERROR [Engine] StandardWrapperValve[project]: Servlet.service() for servlet project threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

at java.util.Hashtable.containsKey(Hashtable.java:307)
at com.scap.handle.ControlStatusContainer.deleteUser(ControlStatusContainer.java:70)
at web.shnController.handleRequest(shnController.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
```

Anyone got a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing your code, no, I have no advice. This is almost certainly a bug in your code or spring config, and nothing to do with JBoss.

Comment: Yes. You are totally right. I tried to create a new controller and view, and that worked.

I know now what the error is. I was missing some get params, and the try-catch did not cover this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to insert some tracing in `com.scap.handle.ControlStatusContainer.deleteUser` since the HashMap used in `ControlStatusContainer.java` line 70 seems not initialized properly.